# This dependency was not found: components/main/Footer in ./node_modules..../src/App.vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

#### my Error:

> components/main/Footer in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/App.vue

#### my components tree on screenshot below:

[image: components tree]

#### my App.vue

```js
<script>

import Footer from 'components/main/Footer';

export default {
  components: {Footer},
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to your Vue.js powered Spring Boot App'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

#### My router:

```
import App from './../App'

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/main',
      name: 'App',
      component: App
    },
```

#### My Config:

```js
'use strict'
// Template version: 1.3.1
// see http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack for documentation.

const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  dev: {

    // Paths
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    proxyTable: {
      // proxy all webpack dev-server requests starting with /api to our Spring Boot backend (localhost:8088)
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8088',
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    },

    // Various Dev Server settings
    host: 'localhost', // can be overwritten by process.env.HOST
    port: 8080, // can be overwritten by process.env.PORT, if port is in use, a free one will be determined
    autoOpenBrowser: true,
    errorOverlay: true,
    notifyOnErrors: true,
    poll: false, // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-watchoptions-

    /**
     * Source Maps
     */

    // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#development
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

    // If you have problems debugging vue-files in devtools,
    // set this to false - it *may* help
    // https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/options.html#cachebusting
    cacheBusting: true,

    cssSourceMap: true
  },

  build: {
    // Template for index.html
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../target/dist/index.html'),

    // Paths
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../target/dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',

    /**
     * Source Maps
     */

    productionSourceMap: true,
    // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#production
    devtool: '#source-map',

    // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
    // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
    // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
    // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],

    // Run the build command with an extra argument to
    // View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
    // `npm run build --report`
    // Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
    bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report

  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

First, please remove the quotes around the import statement. No clue why those are there :)
Second, try adding ".vue" to the Footer import

```
import Footer from './components/main/Footer.vue'
```

Comment: Try './ccomponents/main/Footer.vue'

Comment: may be something in configuration?

Comment: Maybe, can you post your webpack config? And also for good measure, the contents of Footer.vue?

Comment: @MoreAl' are you sure you've used the code in this answer exactly as it appears? The important part is the `./` at the start of the path

Comment: FYI, the vue-loader doesn't need you to add the `.vue` suffix but it doesn't hurt either :)

Comment: Phil, Marina Mosti, it seems like problem solved, but now i've got another mistake, anyway thanks a lot

Comment: @MoreAl' don't forget to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error. This might be resolve by simply running command to update npm by

```
npm i -g npm
```

then by giving the correct path of your component but also add `@/` before name of the component as

```
import UserDetail from '@/components/user-detail';
```

This will solve the problem.

Answer (score -6):

**Problem solved by correcting path to component:**

```
import Footer from './components/main/Footer.vue'
```

Comment: This is quite literally what the other answer says. You should [accept that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) instead of adding a duplicate